# Limited excerpt with readmore

Tags: excerpt

I wanted limited excerpt (40 words) with readmore link...I used this code below:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_excerpt',get_the_excerpt().'<a href="'.get_permalink().'"> read more </a>'); ?>
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: You've got the answers, but you can always refer to [`the_excerpt();` on WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt).

Comment: No question in this question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the default filter for the length of `the_excerpt`

```
// Changing excerpt length
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 40;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

Comment: thanks bueltge,
It' not working...because my code...can u tell me what's wrong...

My code is:  

    <?php $text = $post->post_excerpt;if (strlen($text) > 40) {  
    $text = substr($text,0,strpos($text,' ',40)); } ;  
    $text = $text . '';  
      
    echo apply_filters('the_excerpt',get_the_excerpt().'<a href="'.get_permalink().'"> Read More </a>'); ?>  

please help me...

Comment: all your code is wrong for your question; use my code on the answer and put in a plugin or copy in your `functions.php` of your theme and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to Bültge's answer. You can also alter the "Read more" text:

```
function replaceMoreText() {
    global $post; // may be you don't need this, it depends
    return '<p class="new-read-more-text"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . __('New read more text') . '</a></p>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'replaceMoreText');
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everybody,

I solved my problem....

in function.php

```
function get_excerpt($count){
$permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
$excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a href="'.$permalink.'">Read More</a>';
return $excerpt;
}
```

in category.php

```
<?php echo get_excerpt(40); ?>
```